# Interactive commands are not working when using Jest with Bash

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, git-bash, snapshot

Whenever I enter an interactive command I get no execution. This has also been an issue running other apps from Bash.

The command to update a snapshot test in Jest is 'u', but when I try running that or other variations I get nothing at all.

```
 › 1 snapshot failed.
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot failed from 1 test suite. Inspect your code changes or press 'u' to update them.

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   1 failed, 1 total
Time:        5.674s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

u
-u
'u'
$ -u

see nothing is happening when I enter these things
```

When I use Ctrl + c to exit, this is what I see.

```
u
-u
'u'
$ -u

see nothing is happening when I enter these things

^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? u
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? -u
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? 'u'
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? $ -u
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? see nothing is happening when I enter these thi
```